# Combine two lists in Excel and add new values to old values

Tags: excel

In Excel I have an old list of downloads by country like this:

Country     |      Downloads

USA           |               20
Canada       |              50

etc....

Now I have a new list of downloads (since the previous list was created) in the same format. I need to combine the two and add the values of the old list with the new. There are also downloads from countries that didn't download before and they need to be added at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the rare places where Data->Consolidate is useful.  It does exactly what you want.  Add the two ranges as references, and it will output the combined table using whatever function you want, here `SUM`.

**Starting point**
[image: Consolidate usage]

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Did you ever know that your my hero?